# how to remain old image file in mvc c#

Tags: c#, image, model-view-controller, upload

im new to .net.. just start my mvc c#..

i have a problem here.. im trying to update my logo after insert it. if i dont select the image file, the logo location (im store the location part only in the db) come "null"..

here the controller:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(payroll_Company payroll_company)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase txtUploadFile = Request.Files["txtUploadFile"];

            if (txtUploadFile != null && txtUploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string logo = txtUploadFile.FileName;
                payroll_company.comp_logo = logo;

                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Logo/"), logo);
                txtUploadFile.SaveAs(path);
            }
            else
            {
                //payroll_Company comp = db.payroll_Company.Find(payroll_company.comp_id);
                //payroll_company.comp_logo = comp.comp_logo;
            }

            db.Entry(payroll_company).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(payroll_company);
    }
```

here the view:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-md-2">Logo</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
         <input type="file" name="txtUploadFile" id="txtUploadFile" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

how can i edit the company information if i dont select the image file and remain the old image?? hope someone out there can help me solve this..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var logoPath = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Logo/")).OrderByDescending(f => File.GetCreationTime(f)).FirstOrDefault();
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(logoPath))
{
    payroll_company.comp_logo = Path.GetFileName(logoPath);
}
```

Add code to your `else` part,because what you need is the last image file,it also means that it was created laster than other image files.Otherwise,you need to read it from db first,yes,you have already do it.

After your answer,it seems your `payroll_company` just one property!,so why do you save it? you just need skip `the save code`,and leave `the return code` when there is no image uploaded

Your exception means your object already attched by context,so you must detach it first,then attach again

```
var _dc = (IObjectContextAdapter)db;
var _oc = _dc.ObjectContext;
var key;// = payroll_company.Key;
ObjectStateEntry ose;
if (_oc.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(key, out ose))
{
    var _entity = (payroll_Company)ose.Entity;
    db.Entry(_entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
}
db.payroll_Company.Attach(payroll_company);
db.Entry(payroll_company).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Comment: im trying to read it back from the db but the code above give an error

"An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key."

Comment: im think retrieve the old name from the db is the safe solution.. can u help me fix the error?

Comment: no i store my company information such as company name, desc,... not 1 property only..